# Method to download KITTY evaluation dataset

Tags: dataset, object-detection

I am interested in downloading [KITTY dataset](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/6235193/6247647/06248074.pdf) for object detection. I have searched in the [KITTY site](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_object.php) (and [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0278364913491297)) where I can find the samples for training (which is comprised of 7481 training images) and the corresponding labels for object detection, but I could not locate any link for the test set.

Does anyone know how I could find the test (evaluation) set which comprised of 7518 test images (as mentioned in the site) with the corresponding annotations (labels)?

This shouldn't be too hard. Unless the test dataset is not released and the evaluation is done on site.

Comment: I have links to the test images but not test labels. https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/avg-kitti/data_object_image_2.zip. This one contains all training and testing images (7481+7518), change 'image' to 'label' give you the training label set.

Comment: Υes you are right. I have this file also. I haven't noticed it contained both image sets. But what about test label set? It's not available?

Comment: I can't find it either, maybe you can send an email?

Comment: KITTI has an evaluation server that does the evaluation for you, given your predictions in the test set. The test labels aren't available.